# HTML5/CSS3-like equivalent for software UI design?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I like the flexibility that HTML5/CSS3 offers me when I build user interfaces for the web. These technologies let me create rich website prototypes fairly quickly and, unlike on the desktop, I can skin UI elements such as buttons with ease.

So far I have not been able to replicate this experience on the desktop. Over the course of a couple of years I've worked with Visual C#, Qt (with Qt Creator) and Java Swing, but all require more work for the same design tasks.

Is there a GUI toolkit, possibly combined with an IDE that has UI designing abilities, that can replicate the ease and flexibility of the HTML5/CSS3 experience? Is there perhaps a way to apply CSS-like rules to C#, Qt, Java Swing or other GUIs?

Comment: You should look at GWT. Write java that generates HTML. Then just use CSS to style it.

Comment: Are we going to solve this problem, or are we going to stop from nobody else answering? I don't really believe in giving negative scores because anybody can change their questions or answers. So, can you elaborate more on your question what you really want here?

Answer (score 0):

For HTML5 / CSS3 UI Designing i have been using [kendoui](http://www.kendoui.com/) and [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0):

WPF (windows presentation foundation) is a possibility. This is new in .net 3.5. It doesn't use HTML5/CSS. But it's the closest thing that comes to mind to what you are describing. I will mention what I know, which honestly is not much.

I know it does NOT use HTML5/CSS, but the technique for structuring an application is similar in that you create your UI using an XML like structure (XAML as they call it). And this separates your UI from backend code similar to how you would structure a website.

Using WPF, you have the ability to utilize the power of directx to give your applications media, a skinnable user interface, 3D animations, and screen transitions, etc. In short, I know it allows you to customize the UI far greater than a typical windows forms application that would be developed using the .net framework.

Here is an example screenshot of a WPF application...

[image]

If this is something you haven't researched, I think it would be worth checking out. Hope this is helpful.